# Visual Studio 2017 deploys many seemingly unnecessary assemblies

Tags: visual-studio-2017, clickonce, reportviewer

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition to develop a WinForms desktop application that shows a local SSRS report. As VS2017 does not include the `ReportViewer` control anymore by default, the recommended way is to reference the respective NuGet package for the `ReportViewer` and add the code to instantiate the control manually to the form's `InitializeComponent` method as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started).

Now: When I compile or try to deploy the application via ClickOnce, there is a significant number of assemblies that I don't reference directly and which seemingly don't serve any purpose to the application, as seen in the following screenshot.

[image]

The list goes on and on with many assemblies from the Microsoft.VisualStudio namespace or the Microsoft.Build namespace. These assemblies and also a bunch of translation folders are also found in bin\debug.

What are these? These were not added in earlier versions of VS! How can I get rid of them? And what is this "c" assembly?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found the solution.

The problem was that the NuGet package also contains a Design assembly, which of course references the Visual Studio API to provide design functionality for the ReportViewer control. The reference to this assembly was set to "Copy Local = true", which caused all dependencies to be copied to the output, too.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. Thank you very much for your pointer. I tried setting 'copy local' to false on the designer file reference but the same files were shown to be dependencies in the setup project (winforms, old style windows setup project). Am I missing something else pls?